# Soltar un botón en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el cual se quiere mover un motor con una aplicación hecha en android studio. Necesito que el motor se mueva mientras el botón está pulsado y que cuando suelte el botón éste se detenga.
Pdt: tengo un arduino como intermediario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ello simplemente has de detectar el evento que se hace en el botón. En el Listener `OnTouchListener` obtienes la acción de `event`:

```
boton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
 @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
       //boton presionado
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
       //boton liberado
    }
 }
});
```